# Vertically align center and margin using absolute position

Tags: html, css

How can I vertically center align div's using absolute position? The div should have margin-bottom if there are multiple div's found in single column.

```
.parent { 
    position: relative;
    background: #FF0000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding:20px 0px;
    }
.children_multiple_in_column { 
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    color: white;
    z-index=1;
    }
.children_single_in_column { 
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 60%;
    bottom: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    color: white;
    z-index=1;
}
```

JSFiddle is in here: http://jsfiddle.net/richersoon/m8kp92yL/8/

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Please disregard the horizontal line it is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the multiple items in a div and use `transform: translateY(-50%); top: 50%;` to vertically align.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: #FF0000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.parent>div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.children_single_in_column {
  left: 60%;
}

.multiple>div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.multiple>div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="multiple">
    <div class="children_multiple_in_column">Monday Task 1</div>
    <div class="children_multiple_in_column">Monday Task 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="children_single_in_column">Friday Task 1</div>
</div>
```

Example: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/wzrosnrt/1)

Comment: Can we do it without adding that another div ("multiple" div)?

Comment: Normally not, unless you don't want it to be dynamic (change depending on the content). You could use classes like `.three-children` or JS, but it's easiest to just wrap it. You could just wrap it using JS too.